# In JSF2.0 can f:setPropetyActionListener pass boolean?

Tags: jsf-2

Here is part of my backing bean:

```
public class MyBean {
    private boolean mobile = false;

    public boolean isMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(boolean mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
```

Here is JSF code (in .xhtml):

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="Test" action="#{myBean.testing}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener 
            target="#{myBean.mobile}" value="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

So for when testing this it doesn't appear to call the setMobile method.  It doesn't error either.

Comment: Looks fine, the setpropertyactionlostener is supposed invoked on the button click. Is it not invoking?

Comment: You need to add a little more context here. What is the scope of the backing bean? Do you have any nested `<h:form/>s` around that command button?

Answer (score 2):

Try `value="#{'true'}"` instead of `value="true"`